# Необходимо передать данные на сайт через aiohttp clientsession

Tags: python, aiohttp

Мне необходимо передать данные которые есть на скриншоте, пытался отправить их как `headers` и `data`, но попытки оказались безуспешными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Есть идеи?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример GET запроса с параметрами из официальной документации.](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls)

```py
params = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=params) as resp:
    print(resp.url)
```